# how do I make the link from database clickable and get the content of the url

Tags: python, django, django-models

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from base.models import Prescription

def orders(request):
    orders = Prescription.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'base/orders.html', {
        'orders': orders,
    })
```

the link in question is the last one ( order.presc.url )

```
{% for order in orders %}
 <tr>
  <td>{{order.id}}</td>
  <td>{{order.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{order.presc}}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: your `order` is a `Prescription` object?

Comment: its an image file. which i want to get the url of it to click and open it

Comment: Shouldn't creating an anchor tag resolve the issue? For example, 

```<td><a href="{{ order.presc.url }}">Prescription for order {{ order.id }}></a></td>```

Comment: i tried it didnt work @ManashMandal

Comment: I checked the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/). Here is an example from the doc:

`{% for story in story_list %}
<h2>
  <a href="{{ story.get_absolute_url }}">
    {{ story.headline|upper }}
  </a>
</h2>
`

Looks like my format should work, can you share the `Prescription` model?

Edit: Probably made a mistake adding an extra angle bracket. This one should work.

`<td><a href="{{ order.presc.url }}">Prescription for order {{ order.id }}</a></td>`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<td><a href="{{order.presc.url}}">prescription</a></td>
```